# My telegram bot on Python not working

Tags: python, azure, telegram-bot, systemd

I wrote a bot in Python.
Periodically, it stops working.
The virtual machine works stably.
The running service is always active.

I'm using this library - https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI

Works on a virtual machine on the Azure service (Ubuntu 16.04.5).

Here is the Python script code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import config
import telebot

bomg = "Бомж"
regRusLetters = re.compile("^[а-яА-Яё]+$")

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)


def second_vowels(text):
    pos = 0
    i = 1
    while i < len(text):
        if text[i] in "ауоыиэяюёе":
            pos = i
            break
        i = i + 1
    return pos


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Пришли мне слово на Русском и я его бомжирую!")


@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def repeat_all_mesages(message):
    response = "не могу бомжировать..."
    text = message.text.lower()
    if re.match(regRusLetters, text):
        pos = second_vowels(text)
        response = bomg + text[pos:]

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, response)


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Configured as a service using systemd. Here is the bot.service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=TelegramBot
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=idle
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3.5 /home/rhanza/TelegramBot/bot.py
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I connect through ssl and check the status of the process, I see the following:

```
status bot.service
● bot.service - TelegramBot
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/bot.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2017-12-16 21:06:31 UTC; 3min 8s ago
 Main PID: 3823 (python3.5)
    Tasks: 4
   Memory: 19.2M
      CPU: 930ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/bot.service
           └─3823 /usr/bin/python3.5 /home/rhanza/TelegramBot/bot.py &

Dec 16 21:06:31 botholder1 systemd[1]: bot.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Dec 16 21:06:31 botholder1 systemd[1]: Stopped TelegramBot.
Dec 16 21:06:31 botholder1 systemd[1]: Started TelegramBot.
```

The bot does not always respond to messages, although the service is stable.
I can not figure out what the reason is and how to solve the problem.
Maybe someone can tell the answer?

Comment: Please figure out the point, and only minimum code

Answer (score 0):

Telegram servers periodically send you 504 (gateway timeout) error on longpooling.

Use webhook, instead longpooling.

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase the `timeout` for long polling:

```
bot.polling(none_stop=True, timeout=300)
```

---

If this doesn't help, you can get a python error traceback from `systemd` journal using

```
sudo journalctl -u bot.service
```

and add it to your question.